# What is Best Method for Huge Json String unescape in Java

Tags: java, android, json

I have a project for Android app that download huge Json String and extract useful information for program requirement. But this file really big (Almost 100mb) to put them into memory so I need the read it smaller part.

The Json string I have look like and all string is one line. So I can't read line by line because of OOM(out of memory)

```
{"Tag":"[{\"mySubTag\":\"myValue\/myValue\"},{\"mySubTag\":\"myValueWithAnotherEscapedStringInside\\xyz\/likeThis\"},...]"}
```

Normally, I extract them using tag from JsonObject as string after that I get the string value from "Tag" property and again creating new JsonArray with this string so it was unescaped automatically from JsonArray class but Android doesn't allow put huge Json files(or String) into memory. I have tried to delete backslash via streaming it but it wasn't correct unescape method if the subTag value has an escaped character inside.

**My question is that** what is best and performance friendly way to do this job?

(Note: Sorry for bad English)

**UPDATE 1:**

After @pskink recommandation I have used android.util.JsonReader and I have written a code something like that:

```
JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(f));//f is defined previous code but not shown!
jsonReader.beginObject();                   
String name = jsonReader.nextName();        
String value = jsonReader.nextString();         
Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "name: " + name);   
Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "value: " + value.length());//value is so big I only care about its length
JsonReader jsonReader1 = new JsonReader(new StringReader(value));
while (jsonReader1.hasNext()) {
    JsonToken token = jsonReader1.peek();
    switch (token) {
        case BEGIN_ARRAY:
            jsonReader1.beginArray();
            Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "BEGIN_ARRAY");
            continue;
        case END_ARRAY:
            jsonReader1.endArray();
            Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "END_ARRAY");
            continue;
        case BEGIN_OBJECT:
            jsonReader1.beginObject();
            Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "BEGIN_OBJECT");
            continue;
        case END_OBJECT:
            jsonReader1.endObject();
            Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "END_OBJECT");
            continue;
        case NAME:
            Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "name: " + jsonReader1.nextName());
            continue;
        case STRING:
            Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "String: " + jsonReader1.nextString());
            continue;
        case NUMBER:
            Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "number: " + jsonReader1.nextString());
            continue;
        case BOOLEAN:
            Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "boolean: " + jsonReader1.nextBoolean());
            continue;
        case NULL:
            jsonReader1.nextNull();
            continue;
        case END_DOCUMENT:
            Log.d(AppConstants.TAG, "END_DOCUMENT");
            break;

    }
}
```

**Output I have is:**

```
Tag
69387276
BEGIN_ARRAY
BEGIN_OBJECT
name: mySubTag
String: myValue/myValue
```

**I have confused why the rest of elements of array ignored!**

**UPDATE 2:**

After some debugging process I realized that **hasNext()** method returns "Returns true if the **current** array or object has another element." but current is not later elements so I updated while loop like this:

```
while (jsonReader1.peek()!=JsonToken.END_DOCUMENT) {
    JsonToken token = jsonReader1.peek();
    switch(token){
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: see `android.util.JsonReader`

Comment: @pskink I have updated my question

Comment: read [JsonReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader) official documentation

Comment: @pskink thaks for your recommendation, it solved problem. But I have still some confusion about why this line "String value=jsonReader.nextString();" throws out of memory exception but important is that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pskink recommendation `android.util.JsonReader` solved my problem after writing code with this library. To see my code see my update in question.

Thanks @pskink.